# How could back-end (PHP) force redirect on ajax call?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, redirect

Sorry for maybe stupid/easy/naive question but I'm having a React headless app which obviously does a lot of data fetching.

Sometimes some requests have a status of 4xx or 5xx.

Is there a universal way of doing a redirect to a given url when this occur without touching the front-end layer?

So when I go to mypage.example.com/user/134, fetch data, get 404 returned, could the back-end itself trigger redirect to user/1?

I know I could do that with routing but there are hundreds of routes and I don't have access to the front-end repos yet, wondered if something like this is achievable from the back? Maybe if there's a 404 back-end should send something with header with location set or something like that?

Comment: The server can't redirect ajax requests. A browser (or another server) has made the request, and it decides what to do with the result. The only "redirect" you can do, is to send the response from a new location.

Answer (score -1):

```
$.ajax({
   //code
}).then(function(response){
   //action on success
}).catch(function(error){
   console.log(error)
   //do what ever you want to with error
   //then redirect to another page
   window.location.href="http://url"
})
```

Comment: I need to do it on the backend. I dont want to manually add ajax handlers in 400 places.

Answer (score -1):

I think there are a couple of ways of doing this - You could try writing a custom fetch hook or a wrapper for fetch that always redirects to a particular route based on the response status?